# How can I rewrite all traffic to sub-directory except sub-domains using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

So the hosting provider I use doesn't support virtual hosts or anything similar so I'm trying to rewrite my primary domain to a sub-directory. So for example I currently have:

example.com rewritten to example.com/sites/example.com/

This works fine using the following code in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/example.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/example.com/$1
```

The reason for this is that have other domains on the same server that I don't want to be accessible by the primary domain and to keep my server organised.

So I also have example2.com as an add-on domain pointing to /sites/example2.com and that works fine.

However, I also have sub-domains that are pointed at different sub-directories such as projects.example.com pointing to /projects/ but these just get rewritten to the /sites/example.com/ directory.

My question is how do I (and is possible too) resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I truly understand, you should to add host condition, if user is on primary domain - he will be redirected. Check this, I've modified a code a little bit:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
#Here we're capturing host name, if it has only one point - this is not subdomain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z]{2,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/%1/
#Redirecting to the current host name in folder sites
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/%1/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:**
This was not elegant decision to add regex for domain, it will work only for second level domains, if you're using domains like .co.uk - you have to add them manually in rule like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somesite.co.uk$`.